# Storing each uploaded file in separate folder?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-sharing, ext4

I want to upload files in my web app in such way that only owner can see urls by default, and it is impossible to download alien file knowing its name/upload date/hash etc. But also it is important to keep original filenames when user uploads file.

Now I have idea about storing each file in separate directory with random name:

```
/media/upload_year/upload_month/upload_day/random-uuid/filename.ext
```

For example:

```
/media/2016/11/18/a1b24567184c/filename.ext
```

It looks very easy and secure because it is practically impossible to found random uuid, but I am worried about performance and filesystem limits. 
I have the ext4 filesystem on rota server drive.
So the question - is it ok to store each file in the separate directory? Is it possible to store 1000 - 2000 files with such approach without performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Solved main task with another way - add random uuid to file name (e.g. `/media/2016/11/18/a1b24567184c-filename.ext`) and cut it when serving file in nginx using `Content-Disposition` header. So main question still is doubtful